# Show dependet edge(s) when user click on node

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js

I ´m working with cytoscape.js and trying to show edges between nodes of the graph. I want to show the edge(s) only if I click on that particular node.
for example here I have three nodes **a** -> **b** -> **c**:

if I click on node c then the edge between c and b will appear.
if I click on node b then edges from a to b to c will appear.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById("cy"),
        style: [{
            selector: "node",
            style: {
                content: "data(id)"
            }
        },
            {
                selector: "edge",
                style: {
                    "curve-style": "bezier",
                    "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
                }
            }
        ],
        elements: {
            nodes: [{
                data: {
                    id: "a"
                }
            }, {
                data: {
                    id: "b"
                }
            }, {
                data: {
                    id: "c"
                }
            }],
            edges: [{
                data: {
                    id: "ab",
                    source: "a",
                    target: "b"
                }
            },{
                data: {
                    id: "bc",
                    source: "b",
                    target: "c"
                }
            } ]
        },
        layout: {
            name: "grid"
        }
    }));

    cy.edges().forEach(function (edge) {
        cy.remove(edge)
    })

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.4/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/umd/index.all.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the edges is unnecessary here, just toggle a class for the edge and let the click event handler *handle* the rest:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          content: "data(id)"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "visibility": "hidden", 
          "line-color": "#61bffc",
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge.visible",
        style: {
          "visibility": "visible",
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "a"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "b"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "c"
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          id: "ab",
          source: "a",
          target: "b"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "bc",
          source: "b",
          target: "c"
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      name: "grid"
    }
  }));

  cy.on("click", "node", function(event) {
    let connectedEdges = event.target.connectedEdges();
    connectedEdges.toggleClass("visible");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.4/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/umd/index.all.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephan T. is it possible to give different color for the edge(s) after making them visible?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want the edges to be colored individually or just plain with some specific color?

Comment: Just plain with some specific color

Comment: I have tried like this but it did not workout `cy.on("click", "node", function (event) {
                    let connectedEdges = event.target.connectedEdges();
                    connectedEdges.toggleClass("visible");
                    cy.edges('[id = ' + connectedEdges + ']').style('line-color', 'red');

                });`

Comment: You have to understand something important here. The stylesheet is there for a reason. Editing styles with `.style(...)` might seem easier at first, but in reality the classes that you can define in the stylesheet are all that you need. **Class** in this context refers to the keyword edge. **visible**, where visible the class specifically for edges.